# Is it possible to change the width of the counter?

Tags: javascript, css, width, counter, webix

I have the Webix ui.counter control, and seems like it is irresponsive to the `width` property:

```
webix.ui({
  view: "counter",
  value: 1234567,
  width: 300
});
```

It gives a counter with the default width (maximum 5 digits are visible). Is this a bug or did I miss something?

Snippet: http://webix.com/snippet/e2d461a6

Comment: The snippet you shared has the input sized to `width: 40px;` by CSS.  In order to make this wider, you could alter the CSS to fit.  Have you also tried the property `autoWidth: true` listed here: http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.counter.html?

Comment: yep. `width`, `autowidth` and `inputWidth` doesn't change anything, unfortunately. But CSS `width` works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird that [`inputWidth`](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.counter_inputwidth_config.html) don't work.

But here is an work around : override the default width `40px` of the selector `.webix_el_counter .webix_inp_counter_value`. Check [`css`](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.counter_css_config.html) for adding more styles.

```
<style>
  .webix_el_counter .webix_inp_counter_value{
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

**Working example** : http://webix.com/snippet/47cbb6c9

Comment: Isn't that widget supposed to work like this? 
webix.ui({
  view: "counter",
  value: 0,
  max: 7
}); It is supposed to show only one number, so you can do the count.

Comment: @Valius79 : However we should have the ability to adjust the `width`. It was stated as an supported property on their documentation.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!